# place one mp3 over the other using ffmpeg in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have two mp3 files one is original file 100 second long and other is 3 second audio audio tag file. i want to merge those two mp3 files into one file, also i want to add audio tag after 20 seconds interval. after merging, the merged file length must be same as original file i.e. 100 second, and content of both files played simultaneously in merged file means the tag file will be placed over original file so user can listen audio of both files.
I want to do it in php, also what was the requirement of two files are they need to be same bitrate and Hertz?

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this and where are you failing?

Comment: i used this library, https://github.com/falahati/PHP-MP3
but it will not work according to my requirement, if i merge audio tag in original audio and when i play merged file, it plays original audio then it plays audio tag alternatively, i want to play both simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) and [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) or [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp3 -i secondary.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=20000|20000[2nd];[0:a][2nd]amix=inputs=2" out.mp3
```